# Automatic subsection enumeration

Tags: sectioning, numbering, theorems

For our math lectures I have been hard-coding paragraphs like

```
\paragraph*{Definition 1.1.1 (foo)}
\paragraph*{Example 1.1.2}
\paragraph*{Proposition 1.1.3}
```

and I want to create new commands like `\definition`, `\lemma`, `\theorem`, ... which create such paragraphs and handle the numbering. Every command is nested in a subsection, if you need to know.

Any specific idea what would be the best?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No no no.

`\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}` should make your paragraphs automatically have numbers.

Wait, rereading the question, the [`ntheorem`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/ntheorem/) package allows you to create new environments (not commands) that are automatically numbered and so on. This might be better.

Here's a quick example of how these things would work:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ntheorem}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[subsection]
\newtheorem{example}{Example}[subsection]
\begin{document}
\section{Foo}

\subsection{First sub}

\begin{theorem}
  Here is a theorem
\end{theorem}
\begin{theorem}
  Another theorem
\end{theorem}

\subsection{Second sub}
\begin{example}
  An example
\end{example}
\begin{theorem}
  A third theorem
\end{theorem}
\end{document}
```

Declaring a new theorem involves giving the *environment* a name, then giving the theorem type a name that will display and finally (optinally) tell it where it gets its numbering from. In this case, I have told both `theorem` and `example` to get their numbering from the `subsection` they sit in, but you can change that if you'd like.

Comment: Does not work for me. Texlipse says `No counter '' defined; undefined control sequence.` My documentclass is `\documentclass[twoside]{scrartcl}`

Comment: @Christian yes sorry. I got the `\setcounter` syntax wrong. It should work now. But see the other edit: `ntheorem` might be a better bet.

Comment: There is one more problem. Using `theorem` AND `example` in one sub gives them the same number! But i need incrementing number where it doesn't matter which typ of theorem we have!

Comment: @Christian Change `\newtheorem{example}{Example}[subsection]` to `\newtheorem{example}[theorem]{Example}`. This tells `example` to use the `theorem` counter.

Comment: This means, that i must insert for every new type of paragraph a `\newtheorem{paraType}[theorem]{Para Type}`, doesn't it? I will adapt this solution because it suits the most!

Comment: @Christian yes. Except for the first one (`theorem`) which sets up the counter that all the others use... This one stays as I have it in my example.

Answer (score 1):

You could use your own environment, something like the following:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcounter{definition}[section] % counter will reset every section
\renewcommand{\thedefinition}{\thesubsection.\arabic{definition}}
\newenvironment{definition}{\refstepcounter{definition}{\bfseries Definition \thedefinition}}{}
\begin{document}

\section{foo}

\subsection{bar}

\begin{definition}\label{testmylabel}
Here is a definition.
\end{definition}

We see in \ref{testmylabel}.
\end{document}
```

Note that by using `\refstepcounter` you get the ability to use `\label` and `\ref`. If you plan to load any other theorem packages (such as `ntheorem`), you might like to use a different name for the definition, something like, 'mydefinition', to avoid potential clashes.

Below is a versatile environment you requested

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ifthen}

\newcounter{definition}[section]
\renewcommand{\thedefinition}{\thesubsection.\arabic{definition}}
\newenvironment{definition}{\refstepcounter{definition}{\bfseries Definition \thedefinition}}{}

\newenvironment{flexible}[1]{\refstepcounter{definition}%
\ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{def}}%
{%
    {\bfseries Definition \thedefinition}%
}%
{%
\ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{prop}}%
{%
    {\bfseries Proposition \thedefinition}%
}{}%
}%
}%
{} 
\begin{document}

\section{foo}

\subsection{bar}

\begin{definition}\label{testmylabel}
Here is a definition.
\end{definition}

We see in \ref{testmylabel}.

\begin{flexible}{def}
some text
\end{flexible}

\begin{flexible}{prop}
some text
\end{flexible}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Due to the style of my script i want to use the `paragraph` instead of a whole environment (because the name of the definition, lemma, ... with its number is nicely written in bold text and not indented). Any short command for this one?

Comment: Furthermore, i've inserted `\textsf`. Any way to give "some" defs etc. an extended title like in my example in my first post?

Comment: I would create a new environment for each of your example, proposition, etc- or would you like just one environment that can change the name for you depending on an input argument?

Comment: The versatile environment sounds good - let me see what you can offer :D (Keep in mind that have something like "x 1.1.1 (y)" where this y in brackets is optional!)

Comment: I have decided to adapt @Seamus solution which is much easier. Still i have to check how to implement the optional title i mentioned! Thanks however!